# Memcached PHP Session error: session_start(): Failed to read session data

Tags: php, session, memcached, codeigniter-3

My web application is using **CodeIgniter 3.1.10** as framework and **php 7.1**, and I want to try using **memcached**, because I plan to use *loadbalancer* and multiple web servers.

I set the session configuration in **config.php** as follow:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'memcached';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'localhost:11211?timeout=10&read_timeout=10&persistent=1';
```

So far, I have been managed to set up the memcached server and able to store sessions, but the ***memcached is not very consistent***. Sometimes it returns error like this:

```
session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: localhost:11211)
```

Especially on one page where there are multiple ajaxs called simultaneously. Quite often one or two ajax returning error like above. But when I set using **files session**, the ajax works normally (never return any session error).

Below is the memcached configuration set on php.ini

```
memcached.compression_factor    1.3 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold 2000    2000
memcached.compression_type  fastlz  fastlz
memcached.default_binary_protocol   0   0
memcached.default_connect_timeout   0   0
memcached.default_consistent_hash   0   0
memcached.serializer    php php
memcached.sess_binary_protocol  1   1
memcached.sess_connect_timeout  0   0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash  1   1
memcached.sess_lock_expire  0   0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait    not set not set
memcached.sess_lock_retries 5   5
memcached.sess_lock_wait    not set not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max    2000    2000
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min    1000    1000
memcached.sess_locking  1   1
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas   0   0
memcached.sess_persistent   0   0
memcached.sess_prefix   memc.sess.  memc.sess.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read   0   0
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers    0   0
memcached.sess_sasl_password    no value    no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username    no value    no value
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit 0   0
memcached.store_retry_count 2   2
```

Does anyone has similar experience or know the way out? Thanks in advance

Comment: What storage engine is used for the sessions table?

Comment: i dont use any database for storing sessions @SpacePhoenix

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these values:

```
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max    2000    2000
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min    1000    1000
memcached.sess_locking  1   1
```

understand that each ajax call will run independently that that means they will ask for session_lock as they want. when a lock attempt fails, it will double the wait time and retries and it will do so until wait_max is reach. in other words, your config says if you try to lock and it fails, do not bother.

the solution is to lower your wait_min and increase your wait_max. that should remedy your problem.
there is also another variable to release the lock automatically which should help with the racing problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Codeigniter3. Should I enter these values in the php.ini file that is available witht he frameework. If yes then I tried it but that could not fix the issue.

Comment: make sure you reload your php and verify new values from phpinfo().

Comment: @yodann I'm facing the same issue in CodeIgniter 3. Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: one risky approach is to disable locking and see what happens. be extra cautious as on prod you may corrupt a session data.